# php url_exists function for https urls

Tags: php

```
function url_exists($url) {
        $return = false;
        $content=@file_get_contents($url, FALSE, NULL, 0, 20);
        if($content == false ) {
            $return = false;
        } else if (count($content)
```

How to modify this function to check on content on https URLS as well. This is currently not able to check existense of file there.

Comment: I can use. But dont know how to can u help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the silence operator `@` and see what error you get.

Comment: it says invalid argument in file_get_content function. But i am still clueless what does that implies.

Comment: Seems like the openssl extension is not loaded. Verify that with phpinfo().

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PHPs `file_exists()` that supports URLs, too?

Comment: To answer myself: this doesn't seem to work - file_exists does not support stats on URLs.